# Can content items be automatically unlocked after a certain amount of time?

Tags: content

Most of our users don't understand that they should Save or Cancel when they edit their content, thus we constantly have scores of articles and categories that are locked.  I realize that this can be done manually by the administrator, but editing goes on 24/7, and it's rather tedious to constantly go through all the items determining if the edit has been abandoned or not.

Is there a way to have the locks timeout somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an hourly cron job or use phpMyAdmin and execute this SQL:

```
UPDATE `jos_content` c    SET c.checked_out = 0, c.checked_out_time = 0 WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00'), c.checked_out_time)) >= 2;
UPDATE `jos_categories` c SET c.checked_out = 0, c.checked_out_time = 0 WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00'), c.checked_out_time)) >= 1;
```

**Note:** Replace `jos` with your table prefix.

The above SQL check in articles and categories that checked out more than two hours or an hour ago respectively. I assume that an article and a category should be saved within two hours and an hour respectively. You may increase those numbers.

Comment: Figured it would be a job for SQL, but hoped for some kind of hidden feature in the newer versions.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in feature but you can use [Autocheckin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission/21698) plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to avoid crons whenever possible, but based on the answer from @Farahmand, I put a variation of this code in a User Plugin `onUserLogout()` event:

When *any* user logs **out**, the plugin checks-in any of *their* content, as well as any other check-outs that may have been abandoned.  I wanted only certain user groups to be affected, and to insure that any admin users content was *never* affected (for our own internal reasons - perhaps overkill for typical installations, but in our case we have custom user groups that can be in several of the standard user groups, so have accounted for that overlap).

```
function onUserLogout() {
    $groups_include = '2,4,10';    // Affect Registered, Publishers, and Custom Group
    $groups_exclude = '7,8';       // Don't affect Administrators or Super Users

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->update($db->quoteName('#__content'))
    ->set('checked_out = 0, checked_out_time = 0')
    ->where('( checked_out = '.JFactory::getUser()->id.' ) OR (
        checked_out_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
        AND checked_out IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM scm_user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id IN ('.$groups_include.'))
        AND checked_out NOT IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM scm_user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id IN ('.$groups_exclude.'))
        )'
    );
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
    return true;
}
```

I'm sure the SQL can be adjusted for Timezones, etc., but here's the resulting SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `gdp_content`
SET checked_out = 0, checked_out_time = 0
WHERE ( checked_out = 30 ) OR (
        checked_out_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
        AND checked_out IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM scm_user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id IN (2,10,11))
        AND checked_out NOT IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM scm_user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id IN (7,8))
        )
```

Comment: cool idea this one after user logout

Comment: Nice answer. To avoid adjusting Timezones, you can replace `checked_out_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR` with `checked_out_time < JFactory::getDate('now +12 hours')` - Not tested.