# Can article be automatically unlocked after a certain amount of time in joomla 3?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

referring to this issue in 2014:
[Can content items be automatically unlocked after a certain amount of time?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/can-content-items-be-automatically-unlocked-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

is there a good solution for unlocking items after a certain period of time with Joomla 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a plugin for this, as there is no mechanism in Joomla core. Searching in JED, there is one available: "[**Autocheckin**](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/authoring-a-content/content-submission/autocheckin/)". I haven't tried it, but it should do the job.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this or develop my own plugin